# Excel Formula or Math Help - Desperate at this point : )

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Dear SuperUser community, I have a question in Excel which I'm not exactly sure if there's an easier way in doing a process I currently do today.
At times I will submit a manual PO order to our retail partner for inventory needed by store/item level. when submitting this order, I want to ensure I am submitting enough units for each store to have at least 6 weeks of sale.
What I currently do is determine stores current on hand qty divide this by avg units sold the last 4 weeks to get current weeks of sales. From here I then manually add how many units I think the store would need in order to get the store to 6 weeks or more. When I have over 6,000 lines of stores/item needing review this process becomes very time consuming. Anyone know how I can make this column automated instead of manual or have any suggestions or advise? Thank you kindly in advance.

[Screenshot of excel file w/ commentary for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mMyHi.png)

Comment: `6 * Number of units sold per week - Current inventory` ?

Answer (score 0):

Algebra:
(CurrTotalInventory+WhpkNeeded*EachesPerWhpk)/UnitsPerStorePerWeek >= 6

Solving for WhpkNeeded:
WhpkNeeded >= (6 * UnitsPerStorePerWeek - CurrTotalInventory) / EachesPerWhpk

Convert to Excel:

```
=MAX(0,ROUNDUP((6*P13-J13)/S13,0))
```

MAX(0,...) prevents ordering negative quantities

ROUNDUP(...,0) for whole numbers

I don't like leaving the "6" in there as a magic number.  If management decides you need a 5 or a 7 week supply, it would be nice to change that in one spot.  If you put the "6" in A1, a cleaner answer would be

```
=MAX(0,ROUNDUP(($A$1*P13-J13)/S13,0))
```